# Accessing method variables from one python class in another python class on separate scripts

Tags: python, class

I created three separate python scripts in the same directory. Script one contains a class that gives me my location (in  json fromat) based on my IP address and stores latitude and longitude in a list called **location**

```
#geo_location.py

import json
import urllib2

class geo_locate:
    def __init__(self,location_url):
       self.location_url=location_url
       global location
       location=[]

    def locate(self):
       req=urllib2.Request(self.location_url)
       res=urllib2.urlopen(req)
       j=json.loads(res.read())
       location.append(j['latitude'])
       location.append(j['longitude'])
       return location
```

The second script also contains a class that fetches a location key from a weather website using the latitude and longitude obtained in the first script

```
#get_key.py

import json
import requests
from geo_locate import geo_locate

class get_key():
    def __init__(self,location_key_url,key):
        self.location_key_url=location_key_url
        self.key=key

    def locate_key(self):
        api=[]
        link=self.location_key_url + "=" + str(geo_locate.location[0]) + "," + str(geo_locate.location[1]) + "&apikey=" + self.key
        res=requests.get(link)
        j=json.loads(res.text)
        api.append(j['Key'])
        return api
```

A third script to display the information obtained by the other two scripts namely **location and api**

```
#condition.py

from urllib2 import URLError
from geo_locate import geo_locate
from get_key import get_key
url='http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/'
api='<api key here>'
send_url='http://freegeoip.net/json'

class main:
    def __init__(self):
        geo_locate(send_url).locate()
        get_key(url,api).locate_key()

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except URLError,e:
        print e.reason,"\nPlease check connection"
```

But when I run the **condition.py** I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/c0d3d/Documents/accupy/accupy/condition.py", line 18, in <module>
main()
File "/home/c0d3d/Documents/accupy/accupy/condition.py", line 12, in __init__
get_key(url,api).locate_key()
File "/home/c0d3d/Documents/accupy/accupy/get_key.py", line 15, in 
locate_key
link=self.location_key_url + "=" + str(geo_locate.location[0]) + "," + 
str(geo_locate.location[1]) + "&apikey=" + self.key
AttributeError: class geo_locate has no attribute 'location'
```

How do I call  **location** from **geo_location.py** in **get_key.py**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `from geo_locate import geo_locate`, you import only the class, not the entire module namespace. The `location` list will be at the module root.

You should do `import geo_locate`, and later, when you call the class, do it as `geo_locate.geo_locate()`.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the green check, to let people know that the problem was solved.